# How to make dynamic, in-memory ASP.NET charts purely from codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I am using `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting 4.0` in my ASP.NET app. It works fine in some environments thusly:

```
var chart = new Chart();

// Define the chart area
Grid grid = new Grid();
ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
[... setting lots of chartArea properties here...]

ChartArea3DStyle areaStyle = new ChartArea3DStyle(chartArea);
chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);
[... more ...]

[... build Series, Legends, etc here ...]

chart.SaveImage("c:\fakepath\myreport.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

I have omitted 95% of the code for building up the chart (very complex logic,  lots of looping through complex data structures), which is then saved to disk, and rendered from the aspx page like this:

```
<img src="http://fakeserver/fakepath/myreport.png">
```

In some customer environments this approach won't work because the IIS process doesn't have permission to write to the local disk, and they don't want to open that up. Additionally it's not very scalable when multiple users are viewing (and generating) charts, which will be different for each user.

**How can I generate this chart purely in memory?**

I have been looking at the [ChartHttpHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.charthttphandler(v=vs.110).aspx) class, but can't find relevant code samples. What would be ideal is if I could build the chart exactly as shown above, but instead of saving to disk, I could store the chart in-memory (Cache? Session?) in such a way that I could point my `<img>` tag in the aspx page to that in-memory data and the image will render on the page. I don't want to resort to declarative aspx chart building because the logic is too complex and needs to all be done in c# code. I also can't use any approach in which the chart image is written to disk.

How is it done?

Comment: Is rendering the chart with Javascript a possibility?  In other words, https://www.chartjs.org/ or http://visjs.org/?

Comment: Jeffrey: Thanks but it would take too much time to completely rewrite everything to a different library. jsanalytics: I will look into that but it doesn't solve my main problem.

Comment: @jsanalytics, then I'm not understanding. How are the chart images being rendered and displayed? Can you show me your example code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a complete example including the creation of a chart for other users. But basically you save the chart image to a stream instead of a file.

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    chart.SaveImage(stream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
}
```

I created a Generic Handler to display the images in a browser. But once the image is in a stream you can do much more, like putting it in a PDF or email message.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler
    {    
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            //needed to generate random numbers
            Random rnd = new Random();

            //select 12 random numbers between 1 and 50 for column chart
            int[] yRange1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 50).OrderBy(i => rnd.Next()).Take(12).ToArray();

            //select 12 random numbers between 1 and 25 for line chart
            int[] yRange2 = Enumerable.Range(0, 25).OrderBy(i => rnd.Next()).Take(12).ToArray();

            //select all the month names for the labels
            string[] xLabels = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(i => DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(i)).ToArray();

            //create the chart
            Chart chart = new Chart();

            //add the bar chart series
            Series series = new Series("ChartBar");
            series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
            chart.Series.Add(series);

            //add the line chart series
            Series series2 = new Series("ChartLine");
            series2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            series2.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;
            series2.BorderWidth = 2;
            chart.Series.Add(series2);

            //define the chart area
            ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
            Axis yAxis = new Axis(chartArea, AxisName.Y);
            Axis xAxis = new Axis(chartArea, AxisName.X);

            //add the data and define color
            chart.Series["ChartBar"].Points.DataBindXY(xLabels, yRange1);
            chart.Series["ChartLine"].Points.DataBindXY(xLabels, yRange2);
            chart.Series["ChartBar"].Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

            chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);

            //set the dimensions of the chart
            chart.Width = new Unit(600, UnitType.Pixel);
            chart.Height = new Unit(400, UnitType.Pixel);

            //create an empty byte array
            byte[] bin = new byte[0];

            //save the chart to the stream instead of a file
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                chart.SaveImage(stream, ChartImageFormat.Png);

                //write the stream to a byte array
                bin = stream.ToArray();
            }

            //send the result to the browser
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
            context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", bin.Length.ToString());
            context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"chart.png\"");
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(bin, 0, bin.Length);
        }


        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To display the image in a browser simply point the `src` of the img elment to the handler.

```
<img src="Handler1.ashx" width="600" height="400" />
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to embed the chart directly into the html using the a base64 encoded source on your image tag (via `src=data:image/base64`); this also has the advantage of not requiring any further http requests to get the images from the web server.

e.g.

```
<img src='data:image/png;base64,src='data:image/png;base64,[base64data==]'>
```

---

To do this a number of things are required.

A controller to get the image data as an action result:

```
   public ActionResult SomeChart(SomeViewModel model, int width, int height)
    {
        model.ChartKey = "SomeChart";
        return Content(getChartImage(() => CreateSomeChart(model, width, height), model, width, height));
    }
```

This uses a method to create the chart as follows:

```
  private Chart CreateSomeChart(SomeViewModel vm, int width, int height)
  {
      int Id = vm.Id;
      System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart Chart1 = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
      // usual code to draw a chart here...
      return Chart1;
  }
```

Code in your razor view to get the chart; in my view model I have a list of charts which are just action result methods in the controller that are to be rendered. Using render action will happen before the html is sent to the browser and result in the chart being inlined in a base64 encoded manner.

It is the `public ActionResult SomeChart` controller that should be called by the Html.RenderAction method, and for this example Model.ChartList[] = {"SomeChart"}

```
if (Model.ChartList.Count() > 1)
{
        xs = 450;
        ys = 300;
}

foreach(var chart in Model.ChartList)
{ 
    Html.RenderAction(chart, "SomeController", new { model = Model, width = xs, height = ys });
}
```

The final bit that ties it all together is the getChartImage method.

```
  private string getChartImage(Func<Chart> getChart, object routevals, int width, int height, string chartKey="")
    {
        string name = "Chart";
        if (routevals is SomeViewModel)
        {
            var cvm = routevals as SomeViewModel;
            chartKey = cvm.ChartKey;
            name = cvm.ChartKey;
        }

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var Chart1 = getChart();
            Chart1.ImageType = ChartImageType.Png;
            Chart1.Palette = ChartColorPalette.BrightPastel;
            Chart1.SuppressExceptions = true;

            // Set chart custom palette
            Chart1.Palette = ChartColorPalette.None;
            Chart1.PaletteCustomColors = Dashboard.Support.ChartPalettes.ColorsBigList;

            Chart1.Width = width;
            Chart1.Height = height;
            Chart1.RenderType = RenderType.ImageTag;

            Chart1.BackColor = Color.White;

            Chart1.BackImageAlignment = ChartImageAlignmentStyle.BottomLeft;
            Chart1.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.None;
            Chart1.BorderSkin.BorderWidth = 0;
            //Chart1.BackImageTransparentColor
            Chart1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(26, 59, 105);
            Chart1.BorderlineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
            Chart1.BorderWidth = 0;

            Chart1.SaveImage(stream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
            string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());

            if (Request != null && Request.Browser != null && Request.Browser.Browser == "IE" && Request.Browser.MajorVersion <= 8)
            {
                /*
                 * IE8 can only handle 32k of data inline so do it via the cached getChart
                 * method - i.e. store the chart in the cache and return a normal image.
                 */
                if (encoded.Length > 32000)
                {
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(chartKey))
                        chartKey = String.Format("{0}{1}", name, Guid.NewGuid());

                    System.Web.Helpers.WebCache.Set(chartKey, stream.ToArray());

                    result.Append(String.Format("<img width='{0}' height='{1}' src='{3}' alt='' usemap='#ImageMap{2}'>", width, height, name,
                        Url.Action("getChart", new { key = chartKey })));

                    return result.ToString() + Chart1.GetHtmlImageMap("ImageMap" + name); ;
                }
            }
            /*
             * render using data inline for speed
             */
            string img = String.Format("<img width='{0}' height='{1}' src='data:image/png;base64,{{0}}' alt='' usemap='#ImageMap{2}'>", Chart1.Width, Chart1.Height, name);
            return String.Format(img, encoded) + Chart1.GetHtmlImageMap("ImageMap" + name);
        }
    }
```